# How to generate PDF of contents inside the 'router-outlet'?

Tags: angular, typescript, jspdf, html2canvas

I am making a dashboard where there are different components shown inside the `router-outlet`. I want to generate a pdf of all the components inside 'only' `router-outlet`. I think `jsPDF` will do the trick. But the problem is,I made a `vc-export-pdf` button which is in a separate component [image] . I was checking how jsPDF is used, most of them have used reference to access the `div` they want to make pdf of. Now how do I access the contents of this `div` which is in a separate component?[image]

Comment: This is the [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-etpdyt?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftop-nav-export-btn%2Ftop-nav-export-btn.component.ts). There is some issues with stackblitz but you will understand the logic

Answer (score 0):

This could be really tricky but to get the data of the div you could use ViewChild but just remember that when you use jsPDF rendering from html div, the div needs and it’s content needs to be rendered in order to be in the pdf. If you want to generate a pdf of things that aren’t rendered. I suggest you to create a pdf from jsPDF but all written with jsPDF’s functions not from an HTML.
jsPDF with HTML can also be less convenient if you use HTML2Canva because it takes a screenshot (which can become blurry and also not fit on your page if you have too many things) and you will not be able to copy texts that is on the pdf for example.

Comment: What would you suggest I should use to generate pdf from HTML? Apart from jsPDF

Comment: Unfortunately the only library that I used to generate pdf with js is jsPDF. I first tried to generate from HTML but it turns out that if it is just an image of PDF it is not going to be user friendly. 

I know writting the PDF yourself with jsPDF's functions is a lot of work but it would be much more clearer. 

But there are alternatives to jsPDF but I haven't tried any : https://js.libhunt.com/jspdf-alternatives

Comment: What did you mean by 'writing the PDF yourself with jsPDF's functions'

Comment: you can write a pdf like this : `const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4', true);
    doc.addFileToVFS('Bitter.ttf', BITTER_FONT);
    doc.addFont('Bitter.ttf', 'bitter', 'normal');
    try {
      const imgUb = new Image();
      imgUb.src = 'assets/logo/logo.png';
      doc.addImage(imgUb, 'png', 25, 15, 15, 15);
      const img = new Image();
      img.src = 'assets/logo/img.png';
      doc.addImage(img, 'png', 120, 12, 70, 20);
    } catch (err) {
      this.log.warn('Cannot load images');
    }
    doc.text(
      doc.splitTextToSize('totototext, 160), 25, 45,
    );`

Comment: And then to download it you can use doc.save('nameoffile')

Comment: In here,where will I put the dynamic content? the `router-outlet` contents?

Comment: you can use a service and a subject to get the dynamic content. when the content is rendered you send the value of the new content to the service and subscribe to it in your button component so that when you click you have access to all datas that you need.

Comment: Can you provide me some example of sort, its very confusing to try to understand like this?

Comment: I have tried [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cfdney?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftop-nav-export-btn%2Ftop-nav-export-btn.component.ts) Now how do I get the contents from inside the `router-outlet` ?

Comment: Hello, I'll try to give you an example with the service.

Comment: Here I have made an example where you can see in the console that when you click the export button the content is gathered by the buton component. Of course here it is juste string but you can make more complex objects or event you can get html content using viewchild and afterview init. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-soovwh?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftop-nav-p2%2Ftop-nav-p2.component.html

Comment: This is what I [did](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-etpdyt?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftop-nav-export-btn%2Ftop-nav-export-btn.component.ts). I was able to show the dynamic contents in pdf. Now what to do, when there are images or graphs?

Comment: I see that you are using the html. if you ar gathering thehtml you should be able to see the images.

Comment: I did [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-etpdyt?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftop-nav-export-btn%2Ftop-nav-export-btn.component.ts) And it was somewhat working. But how do I change adjust the width and all of the page?

Comment: This is what I told about the fact that taking html could be very tricky, above all when your page is large. Here are some functions that can help to fit html content : https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF/issues/2911